# Optimization issue: I'm not getting the correct maximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have the following code:

```
DNLbuy = 1 - (x/y) - x*Log[y/x]
DNLwait = (x/y) - x
RNL1 = 
  Table[
    NMaximize[
      {a*DNLbuy*x + a*DNLwait*0.4*y, a*(DNLbuy + DNLwait) <= 1,  0 <= x <= y <= 1}, 
      {x, y}, 
      MaxIterations -> ∞], 
   {a, 1, 6, 0.25}]
RNL2 = 
  Table[
    NMaximize[
      {a*DNLbuy*x + a*DNLwait*0.4*y, a*DNLbuy <= 1, 
       a*(DNLbuy + DNLwait) <= 2, 0 <= x <= y <= 1}, 
      {x, y}, 
      MaxIterations -> ∞], 
    {a, 1, 6, 0.25}]
```

Technically, the maximum given by the second problem should always be greater than the one given by the first problem. However, the second maximization gets weird when `a` is between 2 and 3.25 and gives the following optimal x and y values, which are not **really optimal** (for `a = 2.5` the maximum is 0.244):

> ```
> {x -> 0.371178, y -> 0.381122}}
> ```

The following x and y values give a bigger number than they should for `a = 2.5` where the maximum is 0.3407:

> ```
> {x -> 0.322727, y -> 0.581252}
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you change the method to e.g. `Method -> "RandomSearch"` or `Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"`?

Comment: Interesting. "RandomSearch" and "Differential Evolution" give both different results. 
"RandomSearch" gives true optimal values for both RNL1 and RNL2 between a=1 and a=3.75, but not after a=4.
"DifferentialEvolution" results are slightly smaller than my original results for RNL1 starting from a=2.25. It gives the true optimal values for RNL starting from a=1.75, but not true optimal for a=1.25 and a=1.5.

Comment: I don’t think this is a proper answer, but I’ve had difficulties with Minimize and NMinimize and I’ve only been able to solve them by substituting the FOCs directly and using Solve

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean this specific question?